# JS - multiple eventlisteners and dynamic arguments in one line of code

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to get my head around adding multiple eventlisteners with dynamic 
arguments in one line of code. More specific I want the input[name='txtName'] to
call a function when blur or keyup is detected. I want both events to call the
same function with "e" as main argument (e includes the element that fires the event).

How it would have to be:

```
$("input[name='txtName']").blur.keyup.callThisFunctionWithArguments(e,20,40);
```

This is the code I have at this moment, but I think it can be much shorter:

```
$("input[name='txtName']").blur(function(e){callOtherfunction(e,20,40)});
$("input[name='txtName']").keyup(function(e){callOtherfunction(e,20,40)});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helpful to you.

```
$("input[name='txtName']").bind('blur keyup', function(e){
  callOtherfunction(e,20,40);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='txtName']").on('blur keyup', callOtherfunction(e,20,40));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should work. You can specify multiple events in the first argument with a space separated list.